# Material UI dialog property open does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dialog, material-ui

I'm getting this error trying to create a simple material-ui dialog. I do see the property 'open' exists on "ModalProps", which should be an extended property of DialogProps.

"typescript": "2.8.3",

"react": "^16.3.2",

"@material-ui/core": "1.5.0",

```
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';

<Dialog open={true}
        onClose={this.handleClose}>
```

> (TS) Property 'open' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": ".",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es6",
"jsx": "react",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
"strict": false,
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"types": ["webpack-env"]
},
"exclude": [
"bin",
"node_modules"
]
 }
```